# JEE: how to pass parameter to an interceptor

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-ee-6, interceptor

In my JEE application, running on glassfish 3, I have the following situation:

**MyFacade class**

```
@Interceptors(SomeInterceptor.class)
public void delete(Flag somethingForTheInterceptor, String idToDelete) {
    .......
}

@Interceptors(SomeInterceptor.class)
public void update(Flag somethingForTheInterceptor, MyStuff newStuff) {
    .......
}
```

The variable `somethingForTheInterceptor` is not used in these methods, it is only used in the interceptor:

**SomeInterceptor class**

```
@AroundInvoke
public Object userMayAccessOutlet(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
   Flag flag = extractParameterOfType(Arrays.asList(ctx.getParameters()), Flag.class);
   // some checks on the flag
}
```

Somehow it doesn't feel good to have a parameter that is not used in the method. Is there another way to "send" `somethingForTheInterceptor` to the interceptor?

**UPDATE**: The callers of `delete()` and `update()` have different ways of calculating the `somethingForTheInterceptor` variable. And this is not a constant. The information needed to calculate it is in the REST call. But the 2 REST methods have different input objects so it is not enough to inject the http request.

These are the callers:

**MyResource class**

```
@DELETE
@Path("/delete/{" + ID + "}")
public Response delete(@PathParam(ID) final String id) {
   Flag flag = calculateFlagForInterceptor(id);
   facade.delete(flag, id);
}

@POST
@Path("/update")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + RestResourceConstants.CHARSET_UTF_8)
public Response update(final WebInputDTO updateDetails) throws ILeanException {
   Flag flag = calculateFlagForInterceptor(updateDetails);
   facade.update(flag, convertToMyStuff(updateDetails));
}
```

I was thinking - is it possible for the methods in the Resource to set the flag in some kind of Context, that can be later injected in the Interceptor?

Comment: What could be this flag value ? Could it be a constant in the annotation ? Could you explains the need of this flag ?

Comment: maybe you can add it as an header param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java EE, Interceptors allow to add pre and post processings to a method.
So, the context of the Interceptor execution is the context of the method.

> I was thinking - is it possible for the methods in the Resource to set
>   the flag in some kind of Context, that can be later injected in the
>   Interceptor?

Staless Service should be privileged when you may. So, you should avoid storing data on the server (ThreadLocal, Session, etc..).

> The information needed to calculate it is
>   in the REST call.

Why ?
A Rest controller has no vocation to do computations and logic.

To solve your problem, are you sure you could not move the flag computation in your interceptor ?
By enhancing the interceptor responsibilities, you would have not need anly longer to transit the flag :

```
@AroundInvoke
public Object userMayAccessOutlet(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
   Flag flag = calculFlag(Arrays.asList(ctx.getParameters()));
   // some checks on the flag
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I accepted this answer as it points out that an alternative solution may introduce disadvantages. The best solution will be to implement the `calculateFlag()` method in the Interceptor, which is not impossible.

Comment: You are welcome. In this case, interceptor is maybe not the most suitable pattern to address your need.